# Aligning equations in a cases environment

Tags: cases

In my work, I am trying to typeset the following system of equations.

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
\pi_n  (i) = {n^2}/{\vol(G_n)} \cr
\pi_n (j) =  {n}/{\vol(G_n)} \cr
q^{(n)}_{ij} = {1}/{n^2 } \cr
q^{(n)}_{ji} = {1}/{n}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
```

However, I would like to align the equal signs. If I do this by adding ampersands (see below), too much space is added before the equal signs, which makes the system of equations look worse than before. Is there any other non-manual way to align the equations?

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
\pi_n  (i) &= {n^2}/{\vol(G_n)} \cr
\pi_n (j) &=  {n}/{\vol(G_n)} \cr
q^{(n)}_{ij} &= {1}/{n^2 } \cr
q^{(n)}_{ji} &= {1}/{n}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
```

[image: Example of the problem]

Comment: You could replace the `cases` environment with `\left\{ \begin{aligned} ... \end{aligned}\right.`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that you want to use `\left\{...\right.` around your equation. To be able to align your equations inside these you can use the `split` environment from the [amsmath](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package.

**EDIT**

In the comments both above and below the consensus is that the `aligned` environment is superior to `split` in this situation. Perhaps I am missing it but I can't see the difference in this example, however, as people more knowledgeable than I are advocating using the `aligned` environment there must be cases where it does matter.

Here is a comparison of the two environments for this example:

[image]

This produces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator\vol{\text{vol}}
\begin{document}
\[\left\{
  \begin{aligned}
    \pi_n  (i) &= {n^2}/{\vol(G_n)} \cr
    \pi_n (j) &=  {n}/{\vol(G_n)} \cr
    q^{(n)}_{ij} &= {1}/{n^2 } \cr
    q^{(n)}_{ji} &= {1}/{n}
  \end{aligned}\right.\tag{\textbf{aligned}}
\]

\[\left\{
  \begin{split}
    \pi_n  (i) &= {n^2}/{\vol(G_n)} \cr
    \pi_n (j) &=  {n}/{\vol(G_n)} \cr
    q^{(n)}_{ij} &= {1}/{n^2 } \cr
    q^{(n)}_{ji} &= {1}/{n}
  \end{split}\right.\tag{\textbf{split}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd use `aligned` rather than `split`.

Comment: @egreg I've edited my answer to use both `aligned` and `split`. In this example I can't see the difference but I assume that in some cases it does matter. What is the advantage in general?

Comment: `aligned` allows several column pairs, while `split` just one.

Answer (score 1):

Stab with `empheq`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
\DeclareMathOperator\vol{\text{vol}}
\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align*}
\pi_n  (i)   &= {n^2}/{\vol(G_n)} \cr
\pi_n (j)    &=  {n}/{\vol(G_n)} \cr
q^{(n)}_{ij} &= {1}/{n^2 } \cr
q^{(n)}_{ji} &= {1}/{n}
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is this solution preferable to the solution above?

Comment: @malin If you have more exploits of `empheq`, then yes.

Comment: @malin also empheq allows you equation numbering of each line - something aligned won't do.